# Schema error after altering hive table with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hive with called `test` with columns `id` and `name`

Now I have another table in hive called mysql with columns `id`, `name` and `city`.

Now I want to compare schema of both tables and add column difference to the hive table `test`.

```
hive_df= sqlContext.table("testing.test")

mysql_df= sqlContext.table("testing.mysql")

hive_df.dtypes

[('id', 'int'), ('name', 'string')]

mysql_df.dtypes

[('id', 'int'), ('name', 'string'), ('city', 'string')]

hive_dtypes=hive_df.dtypes

hive_dtypes

[('id', 'int'), ('name', 'string')]


mysql_dtypes= mysql_df.dtypes

diff = set(mysql_dtypes) ^ set(hive_dtypes)

diff

set([('city', 'string')])

for col_name, col_type in diff:
...  sqlContext.sql("ALTER TABLE testing.test ADD COLUMNS ({0} {1})".format(col_name, col_type))
...
```

After doing all this the hive table `test` will have new column `city` added with null values as expected.

Now when I close the spark session and open a new spark session and when I do

```
hive_df= sqlContext.table("testing.test")
```

and then

```
hive_df
```

I should get

```
DataFrame[id: int, name: string, city: string]
```

But I get this

```
DataFrame[id: int, name: string]
```

When I do a desc hive table `test`

```
hive> desc test;
OK
id                      int
name                    string
city                    string
```

Why is the schema change not reflecting in the Pyspark dataframe after we alter the corresponding hive table?

FYI I am using spark 1.6

Comment: Is it a partitioned table?

Comment: Have your [reload](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#metadata-refreshing) the metadata?

Comment: @zero323 yes I have done refresh table

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz No it is not a partitioned table

Comment: How is that Hive table stored? Is that a columnar format with the schema stored in each file -- such as ORC or Parquet? _(for Parquet you should read carefully https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/sql-programming-guide.html#hiveparquet-schema-reconciliation)_

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter It is in parquet format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a Jira for this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9764 which has been fixed in Spark 2.0.

For those using spark 1.6, try creating tables using `sqlContext`.

Like `first register the data frame as temp table` and then do

```
sqlContext.sql("create table table as select * from temptable")
```

This way after you alter the hive table and  when you recreate the spark data frame, the `df` will have the newly added columns as well.

This issue was resolved with the help of @zero323