# Failed Query SQL on PySpark using Python - Table or View not Found

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, hive

I am trying to do a query from HIVE using PySpark on Python connected from SSH to an external server and I am failing (1rst picture).

Details:

```
IDE:
VisualStudio Code

Bash Profile:
if [ -f~ /.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
PATH = $PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop
export HDP_VERSION=2.6.5.0-292
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/spark2/conf
export PATH
```

It is strange because if I open a bash terminal and write:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop
export HDP_VERSION=2.6.5.0-292
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/spark2/conf
pyspark --conf name="test_py37" --conf spark.ui.enabled=false --driver-memory 10g
```

To open PySpark (on the bash terminal) I can get a correct query (2nd picture).

In the 1rst picture, I also try replacing the lines 10 to 13 with 15 to 17 (SparkContext and SparkSession) and I get the same error. All this picture (1rst) using Python 3.7

Can you help me, please?

Best regards,
Mirko.

PS: Picture 01 = Red squares / picture 02 = White squares with red borders
Have a nice day!

PYTHON CODE:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark import *
import os
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test_py37")
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars', '/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/ojdbc7.jar,/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/terajdbc4.jar,/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/tdgssconfig.jar')
 conf.set('spark.port.maxRetries', '100')
 conf.set('spark.driver.memory', '10G')
 conf.set('spark.ui.enabled', "false")
 sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)  
 sc.setLogLevel('ERROR')  
 df = HiveContext(sc)
 df.sql("select * from database.table limit 10").show()
```

2ND TRY (same error):

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.config(conf = conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate() 
df = SQLContext(sc)
df.sql("select * from database.table limit 10").show()
```

ERROR:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Table or view not found: 'database/schema' . 'table'; line 1 pos 4;\n'GlobalLimit 10\n+- 'LocalLimit 10 \n +- 'Project [*]\n +- 'UnresolvedRelation 'database/schema'.'table'\n"
```

[image: Picture 01]  [image: Picture 02]

ADDITIONAL INFO:

1.- I also try configuring the warehouse_location (ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) and newly same error.

2.- In both cases (bash terminal and Python terminal) **show an empty table** when using 'show tables'.

Other links:

1. [Schema error after altering hive table with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983607/schema-error-after-altering-hive-table-with-pyspark)
2. [Query HIVE table in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051091/query-hive-table-in-pyspark)
3. [hive table does not exist in spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897050/hive-table-does-not-exist-in-spark-job)

Comment: Post your code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: @Barmar done. Ty.